# How to get other attributes of elements that are being looped through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looping through a bunch of elements in my div that contain the attribute 'is-required', which runs fine. What I am now trying to catch the name of the element when it also contains 'validate-string', and so far I can't get it to work properly. 
What it should do is when that element contains the 'validate-string' attribute that it should print out the name of the element. Out of testing I will run a function to have some custom validation done to its value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv input[is-required]').each(function() {
    console.log(this);

    if ($(this).attr('validate-string') === true) {
      console.log("Found one : " + this.name);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessName" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Business</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessName" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name" name="BusinessName" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessDescription" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Description</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Description" style="max-width:75%;" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessDBResidence" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Database</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessDBResidence" class="form-control" placeholder="Business DB Residence" name="DBResidence" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessConnection" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Connection</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessConnection" class="form-control" placeholder="Business ConnectionString" name="ConnectionString" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript's native `hasAttribute` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv input[is-required]').each(function() {
    console.log(this);

    if (this.hasAttribute('validate-string')) {
      console.log("Found one : " + this.name);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessName" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Business</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessName" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name" name="BusinessName" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessDescription" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Description</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Description" style="max-width:75%;" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessDBResidence" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Database</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessDBResidence" class="form-control" placeholder="Business DB Residence" name="DBResidence" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessConnection" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Connection</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessConnection" class="form-control" placeholder="Business ConnectionString" name="ConnectionString" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Most of the DOM operations jQuery offers can be done using vanilla Javascript with no problems. Here's the no-jquery solution of your problem:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv input[is-required]')
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    console.log(input);

    if (input.hasAttribute('validate-string')) {
      console.log("Found one : " + input.name);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessName" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Business</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessName" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name" name="BusinessName" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessDescription" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Description</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Description" style="max-width:75%;" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessDBResidence" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Database</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessDBResidence" class="form-control" placeholder="Business DB Residence" name="DBResidence" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessConnection" class="control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-4">Connection</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-8">
        <input id="BusinessConnection" class="form-control" placeholder="Business ConnectionString" name="ConnectionString" style="max-width:75%;" is-required validate-string />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome, Thanks, I will accept as answer once I am able to

Comment: Added a second no-jquery answer.